# Magento adding a bundled product to cart with 'bundle_option'?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, kabel-bundleplus

I can't seem to find anywhere documentation of the 'bundle_option' field in the product options array, when adding a bundled product to the cart programatically in Magento. So I can't be sure how to do this correctly.

But this is my attempt:

```
$json_obj = json_decode($json_string, true);

//define cart
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$bundle = array();
$bundle_qty = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($json_obj['basket']['products']); $i++) {
  $product_id = int($json_obj['basket']['products'][$i]['id']);

  #add individual products to cart
  #$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
  #$product->load($product_id);
  #$params = array('product'=>$product_id,'qty'=>1);
  #if ($product->getName()) $cart->addProduct($product, $params);

  #add products to bundle
  $bundle[$i] = $product_id;
  if (isset($bundle_qty[$product_id])) $bundle_qty[$product_id] += (int)1;
  else $bundle_qty[$product_id] = (int)1;

}

#add to bundled product to cart
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->load(833); #833 = test bundle
$cart->addProduct($product, array('product'=>833,
                                  'qty'=>min(1,int($json_obj['basket']['quantity'])),
                                  'bundle_option'=>$bundle,
                                  'bundle_option_qty'=>$bundle_qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
$message = $this->__('Notice: %s item(s) were successfully added to your shopping cart.', $i);
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($message);
```

}

So the commented out code is adding products individually which works correctly. Now I'm trying to add the products to a 'Test Bundle' product instead.

What I'm now doing in the loop is compiling the arrays for 'bundle_option' and 'bundle_option_qty' fields. Once the loop has finished I'm adding the bundle product (ID:833) to the cart with the options array of the bundled items.

The result is that nothing is added to the cart. I've also played around with the code a bit to no success.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong or if you could point me to a doc/tutorial of the product options parameter that details the bundle_option array (what the indexes are, and what the values are) that would also help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to check the POST variables sent to the cart URL from the front-end to figure this one out.

These were the variables posted for one bundle:

```
bundle_option[1][]  17
bundle_option[1][]  19
bundle_option_qty[1][17]    1
bundle_option_qty[1][19]    1
product 833
qty 2
related_product
```

From that I figured out that `bundle_option[1]` referred to **Option 1** in the bundle.
I also figured that the values of the indexes `bundle_option[1][0]=17` and `bundle_option[1][1]=19` - the 17 and 19 referred to `selection_id`.

Analysing the form on the front-end revealed my list of selection_id's. I figured that the selection ID's would change once the bundle was altered in Admin>Manage Products so I used a look-up to get the selection IDs rather than hard-coding them in.

The code I ended up with was this:

```
$json_string = isset($_POST["json"])? $_POST["json"] : null;
if (!is_null($json_string)) {

  $json_obj = json_decode($json_string, true);

  #define cart
  $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

  #look-up bundle selection ids
  $bundled_product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
  $bundled_product->load(833); #833 = test bundle
  $selectionCollection = $bundled_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
      $bundled_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($bundled_product), $bundled_product
  );
  $bundled_items = array();
  foreach ($selectionCollection as $option) {
    $bundled_items[$option->product_id] = $option->selection_id;
  }

  #get bundle items, quantities
  $bundle = array();
  $bundle_qty = array();
  for ($i=0; $i<count($json_obj['basket']['products']); $i++) {
    $product_id = (int)$json_obj['basket']['products'][$i]['id'];
    $selection_id = $bundled_items[$product_id];
    if(!in_array($selection_id,$bundle)) array_push($bundle,$selection_id);
    if (isset($bundle_qty[$selection_id])) $bundle_qty[$selection_id] += (int)1;
    else $bundle_qty[$selection_id] = (int)1;
  }

  #add to bundled product to cart
  $options = array('product'=>833,
                   'related_product'=>null,
                   'bundle_option'=>array(1=>$bundle),
                   'bundle_option_qty'=>array(1=>$bundle_qty),
                   'qty'=>(int)$json_obj['basket']['quantity']
                  );
  $cart->addProduct($bundled_product, $options);
  $cart->save();
  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
  $message = $this->__('Notice: %s item(s) were successfully added to your shopping cart.', $i);
  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($message);
}
```

I hope this saves somebody a lot of time!

## Edit

Still trying to solve why `bundle_option_qty` is not setting the quantity (all items are qty:1 added to the bundle product)

## Edit 2

It turned out the built-in front-end bundle add-to-cart feature couldn't add multiple quantities of items to the cart either! [Looking into the issue I found that the bundle-quantity feature was an extension called Kabel BundlePlus](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/33997/P60/#t319760), it probably wasn't installed correctly by the previous developers so I downloaded it again and reinstalled the plugin and now `the bundle_option_qty` is working in both the frontend and my plugin!